# Triggering the same Event Handler for multiple combo boxes

Tags: vba, excel

IS there a way I can assign the same Onchange Event Handler to more than one Activex ComboBoxes rather than reproducing the Handler for each ComboBox like CmbBox1_change(), CmbBox2_change(), all which does te same stuff

When using Form Controls, I could assign the same macro to several Combo Boxes

Comment: write one macro and call it from each cmbbox_change() event?

Comment: On a worksheet, or in a form?

Comment: You can create a class and assign all the controls to it: http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip44.htm

Comment: Combobox examples: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/648917-visual-basic-applications-control-array-event-handler.html